# Изменение стилей обведенного текста

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Приветствую всех вошедших

Представьте себе, заходите вы на сайт, и вам нужно от туда скопипаситть какой ни будь текст. Вы его обводите. Текст с черного меняет цвет на белый, и тот текст, что обвели становиться с синим фоном (ну по крайней мене в опере).

Подскажите пару слов для гугления, как такое сделать/изменить на css.. или может такое только на js возможно?

p.s. охота фон сделать оранжевым, а текст оставить черным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это [::selection](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp) с префиксами для всех браузеров.

Comment: спс. с текстом разобрался, с фоном для текста пока нет.